# Заполнить отсутствующие строки SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') as date, SUM((`orders_items`.`price`)*(`orders_items`.`count`)) AS `money` FROM `orders_items` 
LEFT JOIN `orders_groups` ON `orders_items`.`order_group_id` = `orders_groups`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `orders_groups`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `goods` ON `goods`.`id` = `orders_items`.`good_id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `orders_status` ON `orders_status`.`id` = `orders_items`.`status_id` 
WHERE date(`orders`.`date`)
BETWEEN '2016-08-02' AND '2016-08-15' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`date`, '%d.%m.%Y')
ORDER BY `orders`.`date` DESC
```

Результат получается такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, между датами 11.08.2016 и 15.08.2016 не хватает 4 дня. То есть, в эти дни не было записей (0 строк). Собственно вопрос, как выводить все даты в указанном в BETWEEN промежутке, даже если строк нету (12.08.2016 – 0, 13.08.2016 – 0...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql`... Дополните данные на приложении, это будет проще. Нативных простых способов нет, вызов хранимки в `from` использовать нельзя, всё печально.

Если всё-таки хочется силами `mysql` - вам понадобится опорная таблица с датами, к которой уже left join вашу выборку. Можете нагенерировать предварительно таблицу из одного столбца типа `date` (тысячи лет вам хватит? Всего лишь неполные 366 тысячи записей, то есть мелочь), можете строить на приложении огромный

```
select '2016-08-11' as day 
union all
select '2016-08-12' 
union all
select '2016-08-13' 
/*и так далее*/
```

Можно воспользоваться какой-нибудь магией неочевидных декартовых произведений чисел и конвертацией в даты. Для небольших выборок (типичных для разбивки по дням, кстати. 1000 дней - это фигня для такого запроса, но почти 3 года календарного времени) даже может адекватно шевелиться. Что-то вроде такого:

```
SELECT :start + interval 5*5*(a-1)+5*(b-1) + c day AS d  
FROM (
    SELECT 1 a UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
  ) x CROSS JOIN  (
    SELECT 1 b UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
  ) y CROSS JOIN  (
    SELECT 1 c UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5  
  ) z 
WHERE :start + interval 5*5*(a-1)+5*(b-1) + c day < :stop 
ORDER BY d;
```

На стороне приложения опять же этот запрос надо генерировать с нужным числом `cross join` и правильным построением интервала.

PS: запрос, видимо, упрощён для вопроса (иначе стоит убрать пару лишних джойнов), но условие вида `WHERE date(`orders`.`date`) operator` - прямой запрет на использование индекса по этому полю. А судя по запросу - это поле довольно селективно и индекс весьма пригодился бы. Используйте

```
where `orders`.`date` >= '2016-08-02' and `orders`.`date` <= '2016-08-15'  + interval 1 day
```