# В запросе ifnull(sum(sellprice),0) не дает желаемого результата

Tags: mysql

Есть зпрос:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.nal, t2.beznal 
FROM ( SELECT date,sum(sellprice) as nal 
       from sellstats 
       where payment_type=1 
       GROUP BY date) t1,
     ( SELECT date,sum(sellprice) as beznal 
       from sellstats 
       where payment_type=2 
       GROUP BY date) t2
WHERE t2.date = t1.date
ORDER BY `t1`.`date` DESC
```

Запрос работает как надо, но есть проблема, если есть всего лишь одно значение `date` - одного типа `payment_type - 1 или 2`, то строка вовсе не выводится, а мне нужно получить в одном из полей просто `0` если нет такого `date` в одном из запросов.

Пробовал `ifnull(sum(sellprice),0)` - не дает нужного результата - видимо и не должен, как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t0.date, COALESCE(t1.nal, 0) nal, COALESCE(t2.beznal, 0) beznal
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date
       FROM sellstats 
       WHERE payment_type IN (1,2) ) t0
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT date, SUM(sellprice) AS nal 
            FROM sellstats 
            WHERE payment_type=1 
            GROUP BY date) t1 ON t0.date = t1.date
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT date, SUM(sellprice) AS beznal 
            FROM sellstats 
            WHERE payment_type=2 
            GROUP BY date) t2 ON t0.date = t2.date
ORDER BY t0.date DESC
```

Comment: Это работает спасибо, но я не учел что в середине месяца могут быть дни где даты с обоими payment_type отсутствуют, а они нужны тоже с 0 для верного расчета среднего в месяц. Я так понял выход только один - делать join с таблицей где заранее подготовлены нужные даты либо делать это на клиенте - готовим массив с датами - делаем запросы в цикле, плохое конечно решение - думаю надо забрать все даты одним запросом а потом недостающие добить нулями на клиенте, такое ведь не возможно на чистом sql без шаблонной таблицы?

Comment: @rst630 *Я так понял выход только один - делать join с таблицей где заранее подготовлены нужные даты* Нy почему же только один? Если версия сервера - восьмая, то опорная таблица дат генерируется в CTE, а если версия пятая - то в подзапросе. См. например, вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556264/229437).